# SQL Query using ODBC

Tags: php, sql, odbc

this script :

```
 <?php    
    $myfamille=$_POST['myfamille'];

    $conn = odbc_connect('sage','<Administrateur>','');

    if (!$conn) 
    {exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);} 




    $sql="Select F_ARTSTOCK.AR_Ref,AR_Design,AS_QteSto 
    FROM F_ARTICLE,F_FAMILLE,F_ARTSTOCK
    where F_ARTICLE.FA_CodeFamille=F_FAMILLE.FA_CodeFamille
    AND F_ARTICLE.AR_Ref=F_ARTSTOCK.AR_Ref
    AND F_FAMILLE.FA_CodeFamille='".$myfamille."'
    and F_ARTSTOCK.AS_QteSto <> 0";

    $rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
    if (!$rs) 
    {exit("Error in SQL");} 
    while($e=odbc_fetch_object($rs))
           {$output[]=$e;}
    print(json_encode($output));
    ?>
```

give me this error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: output in C:\wamp\www\articlecbase.php on line 24
```

Please note that removing this line make the code works and i don't know whats the problem

```
AND F_FAMILLE.FA_CodeFamille='".$myfamille."'
```

Also i have a similar script but with sql server and it works fine

```
<?php
 $myservername=$_POST['myservername'];
$servername=".\\".$myservername;
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];
$db_name="bijou";
$myfamille=$_POST['myfamille'];
  $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>$db_name, "UID"=>$myusername, "PWD"=>$mypassword);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $servername, $connectionInfo);

if (!$conn) 
{exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);} 


$sql="Select F_ARTSTOCK.AR_Ref,AR_Design,AS_QteSto FROM F_Article,F_Famille,F_ARTSTOCK
where F_ARTICLE.FA_CodeFamille=F_FAMILLE.FA_CodeFamille
AND F_ARTICLE.AR_Ref=F_ARTSTOCK.AR_Ref
AND F_FAMILLE.FA_CodeFamille='".$myfamille."' and F_ARTSTOCK.AS_QteSto != .000000";


$rs=sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql); 
if (!$rs) 
{exit("Error in SQL");} 

while($e=sqlsrv_fetch_object($rs))
       { $output[]=$e;}

print(json_encode($output));
?>
```

and this also with odbc works:

```
     <?php    
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$conn = odbc_connect($myusername,'<Administrateur>','');

if (!$conn) 
{exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);} 

$sql="SELECT   FA_CodeFamille AS FA_CodeFamille,FA_Intitule AS FA_Intitule FROM   F_FAMILLE";
$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);

if (!$rs) 
{exit("Error in SQL");} 
while($e=odbc_fetch_object($rs))
       { $output[]=$e;}
print(json_encode($output));

?>
```

Please help me.
regards

---

```
$output = array();
while($e=odbc_fetch_object($rs)) {
    $output[] = $e;
}
```

Is working fine on many scripts i have
any help please

Answer (score 3):

PHP is complaining because the variable isn't declared before you use it.

```
$output = array();
while($e=odbc_fetch_object($rs)) {
    $output[] = $e;
}
```

Otherwise, if the while loop is never entered, the variable isn't declared, and thus when you `json_encode($output)`, `output` doesn't exist.

Also, I suggest you abandon the old ODBC approach and go towards PDO (or at least the PDO ODBC driver).

Additionally, your code is open to SQL injection.  You should be using prepared statements or properly escaping the string you interpolate into the query.  Namely, you should look into [odbc_prepare](http://php.net/odbc_prepare)

Also, $_POST['key'] is never guaranteed to be populated.  You should always use something like:

```
$blah = (isset($_POST['blah'])) ? $_POST['blah'] : null;
```

or

```
$blah = (array_key_exists($_POST['blah'])) ? $_POST['blah'] : null;
```

Or, if you're particularly paranoid like I am:

```
$blah = (array_key_exists($_POST['blah']) && is_string($_POST['blah'])) ? $_POST['blah'] : null;
```

If the user has PHP parse it as an array, errors can then occur from passing an array to a function.  This can make PHP unnecessary generate notices/errors, so I like to avoid that possibility.

(An example of forcing `$_GET['test']` to be an array would be `page.php?test[]=blah`)

Comment: hi,after declaring the outpout variable 
I get this result : []
please note also that i m using the same script with sqlsrv and its working fine

Comment: @user1413631 That means your query isn't returning any results.

Comment: in my post i said that removing this line from query
AND F_FAMILLE.FA_CodeFamille='".$myfamille."'
makes the script work
but its is working when using sqlsrv(see my edited post)

Comment: @user1413631 The SQL queries are not the same, therefore one of the queries returning data and the other not is possible.

Comment: the sqlsrv and odbc queries are the same :)

Comment: `F_ARTSTOCK.AS_QteSto != .000000` -- `F_ARTSTOCK.AS_QteSto <> 0`

Comment: there are the same and even without them i still get the same result